# I can't figure out the meaning of this statement

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

```
import pandas as pd

def revenue(target, probabilities, count):
    probs_sorted = probabilities.sort_values(ascending=False) 
    selected = target[probs_sorted.index][:count] #there
    return 1000 *selected.sum()

target = pd.Series([1,   1,   0,   0,  1,    0])
probab = pd.Series([0.2, 0.9, 0.8, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1])

res = revenue(target, probab, 3)

print(res)
```

I understand that the function compares the value of probabilities and correct answers in some way. I can't figure out how the highlighted line works.

```
selected = target[probs_sorted.index][:count]
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it? `[probs_sorted.index]` selects an index, and `[:count]` is a slice.

Comment: See [How to handle "Explain how ${this code dump} works?" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta]; in short, such questions need to be _very_ narrow and specific to be on-topic. Ideally, the question should be narrow enough that you can encapsulate it in the title, instead of forcing people to read the question text to know what it is you don't understand.

Comment: ...as part of building a narrow, specific question: Which parts of the line _do_ you understand, and which parts confuse you? Do you know what `foo[bar]` means _in general_? How about `foo[:bar]`? Is there a specific reason you believe the meaning in this context differs from meaning in a general context? What _is_ that reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `count = 3`, this specific line selects 3 `target` values with highest probability. The rest of the lines do the following:

```
probs_sorted = probabilities.sort_values(ascending=False) # sort `probabilities` descendingly
selected = target[probs_sorted.index][:count] #there      # select 3 `target` values with highest probability
return 1000 * selected.sum()                              # 1000 * sum the of the selected values
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your explanation helped me figure it out!